# Discord.js write and edit a json file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a discord bot using node.js, I created a setup command that when is launched creates automatically a channel where some things happening.
Basically, I want that, when the command "setup" is used and the channel is created, the id of the channel, that is assigned to the var "idsetup", is saved in my config.json file.

I need to do this because I have to pass easily the id of the channel for doing some controls on my main.js, now I am using the "module exports" but is very annoying because there are too many unuseful controls to do.

In short lines, I want to add the id of the channel created in the config.json file, so I can take this id for use and edit it.

(i need to edit it in some cases because, for example, if I delete the channel the id in the config must be deleted)

Can you help me?

Sorry for bad English :(

### My setup.js

```
const { Message } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    name: 'setup',
    description: "ruoli con emote",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client, ChannelActive, idSetup) {

            let tembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#42f5cb')
            .setTitle('Nessuna canzone in riproduzione al momento :(')
            .setImage('https://wallpaperaccess.com/thumb/1552191.png')
            .setFooter('il prefisso per questo server è: *');

        var botname = ' ' // setup messaggio con reazioni
              
        const createdChannel = await message.guild.channels.create(botname, { 
            type: 'text', 
            permissionOverwrites: [{ 
                id: message.guild.id,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            }],
        }).then(createdChannel => {
            var idSetup = createdChannel.id;
            module.exports.CanaleId = idSetup;           
            createdChannel.send('https://external-preview.redd.it/UU6NwbCRQ8cDHeGTw9ArrZ25Mtl-4nVmYHVztqqXBNk.jpg?auto=webp&s=6a8ee41f7bcfa5b0429a108de874b4f03142665a')
            
            createdChannel.send('**__Lista canzoni__**:' + '\nEntra in un canale vocale e richiedi canzoni tramite titolo o url qui.', tembed)
            
                .then(reactEmbed => {
                    
                   ...       
      
                    client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
                   ...
                  
                })
        }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        });
    }
}
```

### My config.json

```
{
    "PREFIX": "*",
    "TOKEN": "knaskbadb",
    "YOUTUBE_API_KEY": "dladlabd",
    "QUEUE_LIMIT": 0,
    "COLOR": "white",
    "IDSETUP": ""
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ACCESSING THE FILE**
To access the file, you need require(file), but this will not update, so here is a function to constantly update the file info:
**CONSTANTLY UPDATE FILE**

```js
//whatever setup and other code can be here, as long as //there is no function already named requireUncached
function requireUncached(module) {
delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)];
return require(module);
}
var config;
setInterval(() => {
config = requireUncached('./config.json');
}, 500)
//and now you can get config.json with the variable 'config'
```

**WRITING TO FILE**
To write to the file, you need 'fs'

```js
//other require things
const fs = require('fs');
const cName = './config.json';
//let’s skip the part where you define config
function prepToWrite(file) {
var myJson = JSON.stringify(file);
var JsonCut = myJson.slice(0, myJson.length-1);
return JsonCut;
}
```

**THE FINAL FUNCTION (what to do to actually execute it)**

```js
fs.writeFile(cName, prepToWrite(config) + '`Anything you want to add in JSON form, remember to add a comma before everything else you add, and the extra "}" at the end`', (err) => {
if(err) throw err;
return;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, this work perfectly, however I have a problem, when I try to do some controls using the 'IDSETUP' from config, it returns me a value as undefined

Comment: **I added this in my setup.js**

Comment: then(createdChannel => {
            var idSetup = createdChannel.id;
            fs.writeFile(cName, prepToWrite(config) + ',"IDSETUP": "${idSetup}"}', (err) => {                
                if(err) throw err;
                return;
                })

Comment: **and this in my main**

Comment: function requireUncached(module) {
  delete require.cache[require.resolve(module)];
  return require(module);
  }
  var config;
  setInterval(() => {
  config = requireUncached('./config.json');
  }, 500)
const fs = require('fs');
const cName = ('./config.json');

Comment: i need for example to do this control but I don't know why this doesn't works
https://sourceb.in/dZbeNUX2s7                            this I how I import the 'IDSETUP': const { TOKEN, PREFIX, IDSETUP } = require("./config.json");

Comment: Maybe it’s because you are using const instead of var.

Comment: @GiuseppeParisi click the checkmark to accept my answer as a good answer

Comment: I accepted your answer but I have some problems, hope you can help me... This is how I require the "idsetup": var {IDSETUP} = require("./config.json"); if I try to print on console the "IDSETUP" I get the entire config.json without the idsetup, it's like if it did not take the changes made to the file, then I have another question, there is a way to change or remove automatically the idsetup on JSON file every time I use the setup command?
If you need i send you the entire part of code

Comment: Hmm... I don't think you can do it that way since the values are being refreshed every half of a second, and you can only do it once. I think you just need to do this to access it:
`config.IDSETUP`

Comment: what do you suggest me to do? I wanted to save the id in the json file because I thought I could always extrapolate it, do you know another way to do what I need? all i need to do is transfer the id of the channel i create, when i use the * setup command, to my main, with the module exports i had too much problem and that is the reason why I created the topic... I have no more ideas

Comment: You do the variable you saved it as (config for example) and do `.property`. If the config file looked like this:
`{"Id" : "anyid"}`
You can get the id by doing `config.Id` OR `config[Id]`. The one with the []s is helpful if you want to grab a property from a defined variable, like if your bot saves usernames, it could return their info by doing it like `config[msg.author.username]`.